Does this recurrent sequence have a limit?
I have a sequence $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 0$,
$$
a_k =
\frac{k\left(k+2\right)+\left(k+1\right)}
{k\left(k+2\right)}\left[a_{k-1} -
\frac{k-1}{k\left(k-2\right) +
\left(k-1\right)}\,a_{k-2}\right]
$$
for $k \geq 3$,
I want to know whether this sequence would converge to $0$ or not.
By computing the terms up to the $50000$-th term, I find that the sequence seems to converge around $-0.4$. However, the equality doesn't hold if we replace each term with a constant, because
\begin{align}
1 & > \frac{k(k+2)+(k+1)}{k(k+2)}\left[1 -\frac{k-1}{k(k-2) + (k-1)}\right]
\\[2mm] & =
\frac{(k+2)k(k-2)+(k+1)(k-2)}{(k+2)k(k-2) + (k+2)(k-1)}
\end{align}
and the sequence is indeed strictly decreasing for large $k$.
Moreover, for each fixed k, the ''characteristic equation'' would have two roots lying between $0$ and $1$, suggesting the sequence is shrinking to zero.
Hence I find it a bit paradoxical, can somebody give me some hints on how to prove the convergence of such a sequence?

@YvesDaoust: Thanks for pointing it out, I got the inequality reversed previously, it is corrected to $1>...$, which is consistent with the quadratic equation $x^2 - \frac{k(k+2)+(k+1)}{k(k+2)}(x -\frac{k-1}{k(k-2)+(k-1)})$ having two roots lying between $0$ and $1$.

I would be very interested to know where this particular recurrence came from. What is its significance for some other question you wanted to answer?

Hi Somos, the sequence is inspired by geometric distribution, where we might think of $a_n$ as the probability of getting $n$ failures before success. Denote $\epsilon$ as the probability of success, we would have: $a_n\frac{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon + \epsilon(1-\epsilon)} + a_{n+2}\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon + (1-\epsilon)\epsilon}=a_{n+1}$, in this case, we know initial value in the form of $a_1=a,a_2=(1-\epsilon)a$ would imply a solution with $\lim_n a_n=\lim_n(1-\epsilon)^{n-1}=0$, and they are unique in the sense that if $\frac{a_2}{a_1} \neq (1-\epsilon)$, then $\lim_n a_n \neq 0$.

And a bigger question I want to explore is suppose we allow $\epsilon$ to vary across $n$, do we still have $\frac{a_2}{a_1} = (1-\epsilon_1)$ as the "unique solution" that has the limit of sequence converging to $0$? This question is a special case where I take $\epsilon_n = \frac{n}{n+1}$. And I tend to believe the answer to the above question is Yes, if we take $\epsilon = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$ or $\epsilon = \frac{\log{n}}{\log{(n+1)}}$

By the way, I believe the more common adjective form is recursive sequence instead of recurrent sequence (although both seem to be formally correct).

The question is about a sequence that satisfies the recursion

$$
a_k =
\frac{k\left(k+2\right)+\left(k+1\right)}
{k\left(k+2\right)}\left[a_{k-1} -
\frac{k-1}{k\left(k-2\right) +
\left(k-1\right)}\,a_{k-2}\right]
$$

Given the initial values of $a_1$ and $a_2$, then the sequence has an
asymptotic expansion
$$ a_n = \left(-\frac25 a_1 + \frac8{11}a_2\right) \left(
1 + \frac2n + \frac1{n^2} + \frac5{n^3} + \frac7{n^4} + \frac{33}{n^5}
 + \frac{91}{n^6} + \dots\right). \tag1 $$
The power series coefficients can be found by the method of undetermined
coefficients.
The coefficients of $a_1$ and $a_2$ are sequence limits and can be
closely approximated to any arbitrary degree using
Richardson extrapolation. Thus, if $a_n$ converges to a limit $L$, then
$L$ can be approximated arbitrarily closely by $a_n$ if $n$ is big enough.
Convergence can be accelerated, for example, by using the sequence
$\,2a_{2n}-a_{n}\,$ and even further by using the sequence
$\,(8a_{4n}-6a_{2n}+a_{n})/3,\,$ and so on.
Given a close enough approximation to a real number, there are techniques
to identify a closed form for it. In the present case, the two limits are
easily recognized as simple rational numbers.

Hi Somos, many thanks for your answer, I start with the initial values $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1$ and the sequence indeed "converges'' around $8/11$. Could you explain a bit more on how you derived the asymptotic form of $a_n$? That would be very helpful.

@JakeZHANGShiyu I studied the rate of convergence to the limit and found it behaved as a constant times $1/n$. I determined the constant and refined the convergence and kept removing the $1/n^2$ term and so on. Later, I realized I could use undetermined coefficients method to speed up the process.

I don't quite understand. How does this expression help us to know if the recurrence converges? After all in this form, I don't think I can calculate its convergence radius

@ConnFus This is an asymptotic expansion that could have a zero radius of convergence. This paper proves that this is indeed the case but nevertheless it does not tell how to determine the leading coefficient from $a_1$ and $a_2$, which is the main problem here. There is also a second solution with behaviour $a_n\sim \frac{c}{n!}$ with some $c$.

@Gary As I read the question, we're asked to tell whether the recurrence converges. So if $
1 + \frac2n + \frac1{n^2} + \frac5{n^3} + \frac7{n^4} + \frac{33}{n^5}

\frac{91}{n^6} + \dots$ has a convergence radius of 0, then the recurrence only converges for $a_0=a_1=0$, so we're done, aren't we?


@ConnFus That is not the case. Read a bit about asymptotic expansions. Perfectly fine, complex analytic functions posses divergent asymptotic expansions. The answer should use $\sim$ instead of $=$ though.

@Gary That's quite surprising to me. The common usage of asymptotic growth I am used to would mean $\lim a_n/ \left(
1 + \frac2n + \frac1{n^2} + \frac5{n^3} + \frac7{n^4} + \frac{33}{n^5}

\frac{91}{n^6} + \dots\right) = \text{some-constant-not-0}$. So the word "asymptotically" here denotes a different concept?


@ConnFus I am talking about asymptotic expansions: https://dlmf.nist.gov/2.1.iii

Hi @Somos, with the paper recommended by Gary, I now have a rough idea of how to determine the coefficients in the asymptotic expansions, but it is still magic to me how to determine the coefficient in front of the initial value $a_0$ and $a_1$. Would you mind explaining more about how you got them? Many thanks in advance!

@JakeZHANGShiyu Thanks for that comment! I have added a paragraph about finding the limits.

The other approach is suggested by the answer provided by Einar Rødland to my other question.  The trick is to notice that in the recursive relation
$$\begin{align*}a_k \frac{k*(k+2)}{k*(k+2) +(k+1)} + a_{k-2}\frac{(k-1)}{k*(k-2) +(k-1)} = a_{k-1} \;, k \geq 3 \\
a_{k+2} \frac{(k+2)*(k+4)}{(k+2)*(k+4) +(k+3)} + a_k \frac{k+1}{k*(k+2) +(k+1)} = a_{k+1} \end{align*}$$  the coefficients in front of $a_k$ from the two equations sum up to one.
So we can actually find an auxiliary sequence $\{h_k\}$, such that $\frac{h_{k-1}}{h_{k}+h_{k-1}} = \frac{k*(k+2)}{k*(k+2)+(k+1)}$ and $\frac{h_{k}}{h_{k}+h_{k-1}} = \frac{k+1}{k*(k+2)+(k+1)}$. Matching the coefficients starting from $\frac{2}{3+2} = \frac{h_0}{h_1+h_0}$ allows us to construct such a sequence as $$h_0=3, h_1 =2, h_k = \Pi_{i=4}^{k+2} \frac{1}{i} * (k+1) \; \, , k \geq 2$$
This allows us to rephrase the equations into:
$$\begin{align*}a_k\frac{h_{k-1}}{h_k +h_{k-1}} + a_{k-2}\frac{h_{k-2}}{h_{k-2} +h_{k-3}} &= a_{k-1} \frac{h_{k-1} +h_{k-2}}{h_{k-1} +h_{k-2}} \\
\Rightarrow (\frac{a_k}{h_k+h_{k-1}} - \frac{a_{k-1}}{h_{k-1}+h_{k-2}})h_{k-1}&=(\frac{a_{k-1}}{h_{k-1}+h_{k-2}} - \frac{a_{k-2}}{h_{k-2}+h_{k-3}})h_{k-2}\\ \Rightarrow (\frac{a_k}{h_k+h_{k-1}} - \frac{a_{k-1}}{h_{k-1}+h_{k-2}}) &= (\frac{a_2}{h_2+h_1} - \frac{a_1}{h_1+h_0}) \frac{h_1}{h_{k-1}}
\end{align*}$$
Hence $a_k = (h_k+h_{k-1})[a_0 + (\frac{a_2}{h_2+h_1} - \frac{a_1}{h_1+h_0})*h_1*( \sum_{i}^{k-1}\frac{1}{h_i})]$, and since $\lim_k \frac{(h_k +h_{k-1})}{h_i} = 0$ for all $i< (k-1)$ and $\lim_k \frac{(h_k +h_{k-1})}{h_{k-1}} = \lim_k \frac{k*(k+2)+(k+1)}{k*(k+2)}=1$, we know:
$$\lim_k a_k = h_1*(\frac{a_2}{h_2+h_1} - \frac{a_1}{h_1+h_0})=2*(\frac{a_2}{3/4+2} - \frac{a_1}{5})=\frac{8}{11}a_2-\frac{2}{5}a_1$$
